# Can this simple scheduling app be done in SP OOB

Tags: schedule

...or would you need to write code?

- Event registration system
- Corporate events are entered into a list with a date assigned (could be a calendar or list view)
- Users register for the event
- *** Only a certain number of users can register for an event before it is marked full

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with no custom server code, but with custom front end code like with javascript and jQuery.  I've modified the Fab 40 template ([Employee Training Scheduling and Materials](http://www.techsolutions.net/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=fvYgytl3dyo=&tabid=69)) that does this and hand rolled my own much more advanced system using ootb components and custom javascript.

So yes, it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with a little javascript and a dataview web part. Make sure you have a capacity field for your event, and a registrants list. Use the javascript to query the capacity when the page loads and hide or show a registration button based on the result. This works well in a meeting workspace where out of the box, lists are filtered by event.